# adding and updating name/values of a vector efficiently in R

Tags: r, vector, data-mining

I want to append a key/value pair to a vector:

```
> myVector<-c()
> myKey<-"keyName"
> myVector<-c(myVector,myKey=10)
```

result:

```
> myVector
myKey
10
```

but I wish it would be:

```
 > myVector
    keyName
    10
```

I know that it's possible to write code like this:

```
> myVector["keyName"]<-10
```

but it takes too much time when myVector is large in size and number of key/vlaue pairs to append are alot too.because it searches in the vector to find "keyName" so if it exists, updates it with new value otherwise appends a new key/value pair.

Comment: `setNames(10, myKey)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's surely a better way than this, but it does work, and prevents the searching through of a large vector when naming the element.

```
myVector<-c()
myKey<-"keyName"
new <- c( dummyKey = 10 )
names( new ) <- myKey
myVector<-c(myVector,new)
```

I'd also add that pre-allocating your vector before filling (ass opposed to appending at each step) will probably make a big difference in your processing time, for example (preferably do this without the loop, but this hopefully gets the idea across):

```
N = 20
myVector <- c( mode = "numeric", length = N )
myVector.names <- c( mode = "character", length = N )
for( i in seq_len( N ) ) {
    myVector[i] <- rnorm( 1 ) # replace with a reference to your value
    myVector.names[i] <- letters[ i ] # replace with a reference to your key
}
names( myVector ) <- myVector.names
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be

```
    myVector<-c()
    myKey<-"keyName"
    myVector<-c(myVector,10)
    names(myVector)[length(myVector)] = myKey
```